# How to install OSX Lion onto a Macbook Air from USB drive without any OS already on the system?

Tags: mac, usb, boot, osx-lion, operating-systems

For whatever reason, I have recently come into an early 2008 Macbook Air which has had its hard drive wiped completely, so there is no OS on there currently. How do I install OSX Lion or Windows 7/8 on it from a USB drive?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a bootable USB drive. You can load a Windows Vista/7 ISO image onto a USB drive using [Windows USB Loader](http://download.cnet.com/Windows-7-USB-DVD-Download-Tool/3000-18513_4-10972600.html). But for Mac, it's probably easiest just to buy a copy of Snow Leopard from the Apple Store and upgrade from there. (If the laptop is late 2008) you can also try to make a bootable Mountain Lion USB from a [tutorial.](http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/17/make-bootable-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion-usb-install-drive/)

Then try booting the computer while holding down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key and you should be able to choose the USB drive from the boot menu.